# Show that if $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ has a greatest lower bound, then this greatest lower bound is unique

Tags: real-analysis

**Question**
Show that if $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ has a greatest lower bound, then this greatest lower bound is unique

How do i demonstrate this that something is unique? Someone told me that i should demonstrate that the lower bound and the greatest lower bound are equal but i do not understand how that works

Comment: A very general way to show uniqueness: suppose there are two greatest lower bounds and show that they must be the same (in general, you suppose there is two of the thing you want to show is unique and show that the two things must be the same).

Answer (score 0):

Assume that both $A$ and $B$ are greatest lower bound, if $A>B$ then $B$ is not the greatest, and if $B>A$ then $A$ is not the greatest hence $A=B$ and because we did not assume anything about the set itself for any arbitrary $S$ and given $2$ greatest lower bounds those $2$ are equal.

Comment: sorry but i am confused can't we say the same for all sets though?

Comment: @JohnRawls I am not sure I understand the confusion but: Take arbitrary $S$(which mean, take some set, any set there is) and what I did shows that if the set has $2$ greatest lower bounds they are equal, so I showed the uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

To start a uniqueness proof, it is generally done by considering two "solutions" say $x,y$ and showing $x-y = 0$. This shows that any other solutions $"y"$ are actually $x$. Or deriving a contradiction. I'll present both methods.

$\textbf{Proof by Contradiction:}$ Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $S$ has a greatest lower bound. Let $x,y$ be two greatest lower bounds of $S$ such that $x \neq y$. Then this implies either $x > y$ or $y > x$; without loss of generality (as the proof will be identical), assume $x > y$. But as $y$ is the greatest lower bound, $y$ must be greater than any other lower bounds, which $x$ is since it's also a greatest lower bound. Therefore, we have $y \geq x$ and $x > y$ which is impossible, so we derived a contradiction. Hence, the greatest lower bound is unique.

$\textbf{Direct Proof:}$ Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $S$ has a greatest lower bound. Let $x,y$ be two greatest lower bounds of $S$. We'll show $x=y$. By definition, as $x$ is a lower bound, and $y$ is the greatest  lower bound, we have $y \geq x$, but symmetrically, we have that $y$ is a lower bound and $x$ is the greatest lower bound, so we have $x \geq y$. Then as $x \geq y$ and $y \geq x$, we see $y=x$, so any different greatest lower bound, we obtain the desired conclusion.